# Correct way to write an IF statement but without an ENDIF?

Tags: php, wordpress

Am I doing this right? It works but wanted to ask if what I have done is bad practice?

Originally if the page is home then will get include a php file otherwise if it is a generic page will call in the featured image in WordPress.

```
<?php 
if ( is_page('home')) { 
    get_template_part( 'hero' ); 
} ?>
 <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID); ?>
```

Comment: An if statement can be defined with `if(): endif;` or `if(){}` So the syntax is fine. However the logic may be wrong here - the featured image will always be shown with the code above. If the page is the homepage, the  hero template will be shown above the featured image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is wrong in my opinion based on what you requested in question. You only check if is home and if it is get template part 'hero'. After that no matter what page is you call get_the_post_thumbnail.

> **otherwise** if it is a generic page will call in the featured image in WordPress

otherwise means **else** and your code should look like this:

```
<?php 
    if ( is_page('home')) { 
        get_template_part( 'hero' ); 
    } else {
        echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID);
    }
?>
```

Do not forget to be in loop to call $post->ID
You can aford endif by using `<?php if(){ ... } ?>` or `<?php if(){ ?> ... <?php } ?>`

Comment: Well explained and very true that otherwise means else.

Do you have any good references to learn PHP online?

Comment: Im pretty sure it is okay to call the thumbnail oiutside of the loop for a single page by <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID); ?>

Comment: You can learn php from w3school, i like it becouse have useful and many example. http://www.w3schools.com/php/

Comment: Okay, will follow that up.

Answer (score 0):

no, it's okay. If the condition is not fulfilled, nothing will happen.

Comment: Ive been trying to learn more about PHP so was not sure, hard to find an easy resource to learn php.

Comment: The w3schools tutorials are not bad. I don't know the PHP tutorial from own experience (only some others), but here it is: http://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp

Comment: Okay, will check that out.